# How to replace the empty cells in r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, replace

I have a data.frame in R and want to fill in some empty cells in specific way. Below is the table.

```
Case.ID   |   Resource
-----------------------
   1      |     501
-----------------------
   1      | 
-----------------------
   1      |      0
-----------------------
   1      |      
-----------------------
   2      |    524
-----------------------
```

Here, I want to replace empty cells into the very first value of each Case.ID, in this case replace empty cells with Case.ID = 1 into 501, not 0.

Comment: Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Comment: Just use `is.na` i.e. `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, v1 := Resource[1L], Case.ID][is.na(Resource), Resource := v1][, v1 := NULL][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the blank spaces in your file are being imported as `NA`, this will work using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame to match post
df <- data.frame(Case.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                 Resource = c(501, NA, 0, NA, 524))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Case.ID) %>%
  mutate(Resource = if_else(is.na(Resource), head(Resource, 1), Resource))

df
# Case.ID Resource
# <dbl>    <dbl>
#    1      501
#    1      501
#    1        0
#    1      501
#    2      524
```

Comment: You can use `first(Resource)` instead of `head()`

Comment: you're right, of course. clearly more coffee is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` in base R,

```
with(df, ave(v2, v1, FUN = function(i) replace(i, i == '', i[1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, v1 := Resource[1L], Case.ID][is.na(Resource), Resource := v1][, v1 := NULL][]
```

Or another option is `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, Resource := na.aggregate(Resource, FUN = function(x) x[1]), Case.ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

as soon as you import it in R (let's say `df`) the empty ones are transformed into NA's. Hence:

```
  Case.ID Resource
1       1      501
2       1       NA
3       1        0
4       1       NA
5       2      524
```

Therefore:

```
df$Resource<-ifelse(is.na(df$Resource),df$Case.ID,df$Resource)
```

yielding:

```
Case.ID Resource
1       1      501
2       1        1
3       1        0
4       1        1
5       2      524
```